# How change type of JSONObject when using javax

Tags: java, arrays, json, jax-rs

I have a `StringBuilder`:

My code is the following:

```
String response = sb.toString();
// logger.info("response is '{}' ", response);
                         
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(response);
JsonObject fileStatuses = jsonObject.getJsonObject("FileStatuses");
JsonArray fileStatus = (JsonArray) fileStatuses.getJsonArray("FileStatus");
                    
for (int i = 0; i < fileStatus.size(); ++i) {
    JsonObject rec = fileStatus.getJsonObject(i);                   
    String pathSuffix = rec.getString("pathSuffix");
    logger.info(" the pathSuffix value is '{}' ", pathSuffix );
}
```

I want to use the `javax.json.JsonObject` and not `org.json.JsonObject`.
So, the problem is in `new JsonObject(response);` `==> Cannot instantiate the type JsonObject`.

I know that `org.json.JSONObject` has a constructor that takes a String, but I think not the case when using `javax.json.JsonObject`.

How can I correct my code to make  `JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(response)` take a String and stay using `javax.json.JsonObject` class?

Comment: The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) explain what you need to do.   It shows that this is an `interface` not a `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to its API instead of using `JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(response);` you can instantiate it from your `response`-String like this:

```
String response = sb.toString();

StringReader reader = new StringReader(response);
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(reader);
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
jsonReader.close();
```

Comment: Do you have an idea please about this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66447226/how-create-a-key-value-in-jsonarray