# How create a (key, value) in JsonArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSONObject, like the output in this link:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#GETFILESTATUS

I woul dlike to get the `pathSuffix` (file names) and the `modificationTime` (Dates) values in a JSON Array, like this:

```
[
  { file1, date
  },

  { file1, date
  },

  { file1, date
  },
.
.
.
]
```

My code is the following:

```
JsonObject fileStatuses = jsonObject.getJsonObject("FileStatuses");
                    JsonArray fileStatus = (JsonArray) fileStatuses.getJsonArray("FileStatus");
                                                                     
                        for (int i = 0; i < fileStatus.size(); i++) {
                            
                            JsonObject rec = fileStatus.getJsonObject(i);                   
                            String pathSuffix = rec.getString("pathSuffix");
                            
                            
                            String  modificationTime = rec.getJsonNumber("modificationTime").toString();
                            long a = Long.parseLong(modificationTime);
                            Date modificationTimeDate = new Date(a);
                            
                            
                            JsonObject jo = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                      .add("list", Json.createArrayBuilder()
                                        .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                          .add(pathSuffix, (JsonValue) modificationTimeDate)
                                          ))
                                      .build();
                            logger.info("JSON object is '{}'", jo);
```

I got this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date incompatible with javax.json.JsonValue
```

How can I create a JsonArray that contain the values of `Pathsuffix` and `ModificationTime` like `(key, value)` ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a JSON-Object `filename:modificationTime` you can accomplish this by constructing a Map that holds your `key` and `value` pairs:

```
JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < fileStatus.size(); i++) {

    JsonObject rec = fileStatus.getJsonObject(i);
    String timeStamp = rec.get("modificationTime").toString();
    Map<String, Object> jsonMapping = Map.of(rec.getString("pathSuffix"),
                timeStamp);
    builder.add(Json.createObjectBuilder(jsonMapping));
}
```

After that, for the json from your Link, `builder.build()` will yield a `JsonArray` like this:

```
[
    {
        "a.patch":"1320171722771" // FileStatus.pathSuffix : FileStatus.modificationTime
    },
    {
        "bar":"1320895981256"
    }
]
```

**Unless** you need to construct a certain Date from the timestamp I stronlgy advice to store the acquired timestamp as is. This is because creating any `LocalDate` (or worse: `Date`) from a timestamp will yield inaccurate dates unless you consider the `TimeZone`s of both where the file modification happened and where the modificationTime value is read.

Answer (score 1):

json does not support a time type, that is the reason for the error. What you need to do is to change that into a type json can use. That might be a string that represents the time (choose the formating yourself, so you are sure, that when reading it out again you have consistent data) or easier you just keep the long value used.

Here you cansee what json can use:
https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 0):

try this json structure

```
[
  {
     fileName:"test.java",
     modificationTime:"2021-03-02 xx:xx:xx"
  }，
  {
     fileName:"test2.java",
     modificationTime:"2021-03-01 xx:xx:xx"
  }

]
```